# ListView smoothScrollToPosition() with dynamic children

Tags: android, android-listview, smooth-scrolling

My ListView has children which are of varying height.

As a result `smoothScrollToPosition` often scrolls to an incorrect position!

Is there any way I can achieve a smooth scroll to a position with my constraints? 
I've tried using a `ValueAnimator` in combination with `setSelection()` but it looks quite jumpy.

Comment: Can you show some of your code? Maybe your `ListView` xml and/or your `getView()`?

Comment: I'm not sure if the code will actually help you, the biggest issue is that there is a one of the views in the child element is a TextView that can be anywhere from 1-4 lines. If I fix the height of the of TextView, then my smoothScrollToPosition works flawlessly.

Comment: Do you have children content changing dynamically as well? - if so call notifydatasetchanged before calling smoothSCrollToPosition

Comment: If that doesn't work, you can always manually grab the distance. parent.getChildAt().getTop()/getLeft()

Comment: @sihrc I do indeed, I have an AsyncTask that determines the text to display in the TextView.

Comment: Have you tried this approach? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17473283/82788